# Why generics can't be applied to the same signature?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code snippet, at the first glance it should work, but I receive very interesting error:

`'apply(capture<? extends Generic.MyClass>)' in 'java.util.function.Function' cannot be applied to '(capture<? extends Generic.MyClass>)'`

This error occurs here: `function.apply(wrapper.value);`

What am I missing?

```
public class Generic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper<>(new MyClass());
    }

    private static void method(Wrapper<? extends MyClass> wrapper) {
        Function<? extends MyClass, String> function = (MyClass m) -> m.getClass().toString();
        function.apply(wrapper.value);
    }

    static class Wrapper<T extends MyClass> {
        private final T value;

        Wrapper(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    static class MyClass {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the variable type to (*):

```
Function<MyClass, String>
```

`? extends MyClass` means that this function accepts a specific subclass of `MyClass`, but you just don't know which one.

Although the error message makes it look like the types are the same, they're not: each of the `? extends MyClass` refers to a different (*but specific*) type.

The only thing you can safely pass to this function would be literal `null`.

The acronym [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/3788176) tells you that `extends` is used for producer methods (e.g. "wrapper produces value"). It is not used for consumer methods (e.g. "function accepts a T as a parameter"): that's what `super` is for.

---

(*) Or just use `wrapper.value.getClass().toString();`, and don't bother declaring the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the method generic:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper<>(new MyClass());
    }

    private static <T extends MyClass> void method(Wrapper<T> wrapper) {
        Function<T, String> function = (T m) -> m.getClass().toString();
        function.apply(wrapper.value);
    }

    static class Wrapper<T extends MyClass> {
        private final T value;

        Wrapper(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    static class MyClass {

    }

}
```